# Allow localizing the "Q" and "A" icons in the user profile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, localization, russian-stackoverflow, international-sites

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15479/suvitruf-andrei-apanasik?tab=profile

> [image: Q/A svg icons]

Is it possible to translate those icons for international sites?

Comment: Also [requested in Meta SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3288/83) back in 2018.

Comment: It may be worth editing in the context - as demonstrated in fedorqui's link, other parts of the site (e.g. search) *do* use different letters in place of "Q" or "A" when referring to questions/answers respectively - so the icons should be localized accordingly, per your feature request.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We added new icons for the Portuguese, Spanish, and Russian languages.

Japanese is continuing to use the English versions, but we're looking into whether we can condense the translations into single characters there as well. The search page on SO in Japanese also still uses `Q:` and `A:`, so I imagine we're good on that front at least for the time being.

Thanks for the request!