# Duplicate questions in search page do not have "P" and use English's "Q" for SOes and SOpt

Tags: bug, search, localization, international-sites, transifex

When you browse through the [result pages on a Search in Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq) results show a "P" next to the title (from "Pregunta", Spanish for *Question*):

[image: Questions prefixed with P:]

However, a "Q" shows for questions that are duplicate as shown when searching for [`duplicate:yes`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=duplicate%3Ayes):

[image: Questions prefixed with Q:]

- [`closed:yes`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes) does work well and shows a "P".
- Stack Overflow на русском does show this well ([see](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=duplicate%3Ayes)).
- Stack Overflow em Português does have the same bug [`duplicate:yes`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=duplicate%3Ayes) and also for [`closed:yes`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes) (it shows "Q" in both cases, while it should be "P")

Comment: Is this related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355415/158100 ?

Comment: @rene it is related in the sense that [its equivalent question in MetaSOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4877/83) is where a user reported it. But I think it is different because that one refers to an icon and this one is just plain text.

Comment: Is this a transifex issue?

Comment: @Mast I hadn't thought about it and yes, you are right! I just posted an answer with what I found to be the string. Many thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, it was a Transifex issue. I entered [es.traducir.win](https://es.traducir.win/) and searched for [`^Q:`](https://es.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%5EQ%3A) to find several strings, two of them without a translation right now:

[image]

I just suggested the changes to have `P:` in the translation. Once they are approved by [some of the reviewers](https://es.traducir.win/users) and then pulled by an employee, this should be fixed.